# C - `0` special character appear using malloc

Tags: c, malloc, concatenation, lldb

I'm having some trouble using malloc during a concatenation. It seem when I malloc my pointer, a character is automatically added. This append after many loop who already worked, I use malloc on a null pointer set up 2 line before, I'm using only number for which exist, `cur_len, sub_len`.

It seem to be a normal thinks, but at a moment this special character automatically pop up. Actually, it seem (for me) displayed as a single character when it's printed (see picture 2), but when I check the new_str value through lldb, `'0'` (with blockquote) is in three character...

[image: lldb representation]
When the caracter is printed : 
[image]

If anyone can give me a clue, it tried some stuff, not able to understand for the moment. Thanks to you, I hope I was clear.

**Edit:**
My error --> I wasn't overwritting the pointer returned by malloc from the first index, and because malloc could give some memory which is not "clean", in a memory pool, you have (must ?) overwrite the new pointer from the index 0. (Actually I think it make no sense to not do it.)

Comment: this is simply garbage memory left in the memory you got from malloc

Comment: Please post text as text.  Text as pictures is less useful.

Comment: what is `ft_strcat` ?

Comment: Sorry for the picture, I was thinking it could be clear and a snippet can be test. How should I do to avoid this thinks appening ? I need fresh memory and not something from anywhere x).

Comment: ft_strcat is strcat actually

Answer (score 3):

`malloc()` does not initialize the memory space you allocated, it will often contain garbage from whatever that memory space was used for previously.

If you want to enforce that the memory you allocating is zero filled, use `calloc()` instead. Notice `calloc()` [takes different parameters](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/).

Comment: But note that C malloc() leaving garbage in memory is a feature. If your code is going to write a new string into that memory then clearing it with zero first is a waste of time.

Comment: Indeed, zero'ing the memory might be time consuming and pointless. `malloc()` is more efficient than `calloc()`.

Comment: I've never seen malloc returning pointer with some existing content, some garbage. It could append a single time in a couple of month ? I Should wait tomorrow perhaps xD

Comment: @rSim Yes malloc may get new memory from the OS and it will be zero. Or it might use memory that was used previously and returned by free(). It may appear a little bit random. Many functions in the C library use malloc(), like printf, for buffering output. So depending on what functions you call and in what order, it can affect what kind of memory malloc returns.

Comment: @rSim If you `free()` space and then `malloc()` it again, it's quite possible it will simply yield you the same space, same pointer, with the data you left there before still in place.

Comment: So if it's like that, I have to check, in a first time if malloc return me NULL, and add an other condition to check if the given string is empy and in this case clean it ? Or should I track a (kind of ?) memory leak if it's possible ?

Comment: If I just seted up the pointer that I freed to NULL, it won't change nothing right ?

Comment: It should never return `NULL`, your heap space definitively starts at a different address.

Comment: Because strcat add the second string to the first one, and it's nood the good variable who was used for the concatenation. I didn't use my old string

Comment: I'm adding some content to the string just freshly malloc, it's not overwritten. But this mistake was interesting, thanks guys for this sharing

Comment: You can simply set the first byte to `\0` and it will be a valid empty string where `strcat()` wont mess up.